# .NET Winform - Pivot Table for multiple Data Value columns

Tags: vb.net, winforms, pivot, pivot-table

I need to create a pivot table at the front end after retrieving data from the DB in a datatable and need to update the values of my grid with this data.

I have gone through many articles/blogs but they all demonstrate it by using one Data Value column. But in my scenario, I have **8 Data value columns** to be pivoted.

**Data To Pivot**

[image]

**Pivoted Data**

[image]

Do someone has idea how to do it efficiently at the front end?

Would it be a good idea to embed the data in excel, create the Pivot there and retrieve the required data from excel?

Comment: are you returning the data from a database?  If so, why not perform the pivot there and return it?

Comment: You could do this easily if you could use SQL, so maybe an in-memory database (embedded into your front-end) could help. Try SQLite for example.

Comment: @bluefeet, Pivot in SQL sucks.. you have to write dynamic queries and I have already burnt my fingers with it.. this is not the way to go.. I am sure about that.

Comment: @kol.. can you please give an example.. OR can refer a page/url where i can get sample source code/more info about it?

Comment: @user899055 PIVOT in SQL does not suck and does not necessarily have to be dynamically created.  There are a lot of answers on SO that can should be able to answer any issues with PIVOTs

Comment: @bluesheet, you are right.. there is a way i.e. CASE but it's not applicable in all scenarios e.g. when you don't already know the exact column values i.e. US and Canada in this case, then you are not able to use CASE for PIVOT. Please let me know if there are any other way. I urgently need it.

Comment: Can someone please provide suggestions on that?